# Reset Seekbar using ValueAnimator in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to make a button change a seekbar's progress back to a specific value slowly while the button is pressed. It's like, say, the seekbar's curent progress is 150, it's standard value is 100, and I want to decrease the progress back to 100 while a buttons is pressed, and to move 1 unit on the seekbar takes 0.1 sec.
I'm trying to do this using a ValueAnimator

```
    main_seekbar_speed_reset.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

             ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress(), 100);;


            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress(), 100);
                    animator.setDuration(Math.abs(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress() - 100)*100);
                    animator.start();
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            main_seekbar_speed.setProgress((int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }
                    });
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        animator.end();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

But this code resets it immediately.

**EDIT**

I forgot about adding `break;` to the end of each case.
It means that `switch` has gone through every case, thus `animator.end()` was always called for last, which set the progress of `seekbar` to the final animated value (100) everytime.
Additionally, `animator.end()` means that the animator ends immediately; it jumps to the last value it should be at the end of the animation.

`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` both created a new ValueAnimator, so releasing the button couldn't  affect the `ValueAnimator` which was created when touching the button. It should be declared outside the listener.

So the working code:

`

```
    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress(), 100);
    main_seekbar_speed_reset.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    animator.setIntValues(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress(), 100);
                    animator.setDuration(Math.abs(main_seekbar_speed.getProgress() - 100)*100);
                    animator.start();
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            main_seekbar_speed.setProgress((int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    animator.pause();
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });`
```